# Por que alguns nomes de cidade/estado/país admitem artigos e outros não?

Tags: artigos-definidos

Venho aqui estender a pergunta de um colega que está tentando aprender português.

Para mim como falante nativo da língua é instintivo dizer as seguintes frases:

- eu moro EM Portugal
- eu moro NO Brasil
- eu moro NA França

Mas este colega que está tentando aprender português por conta própria me perguntou qual a regra para isto, e eu não tenho a mínima ideia, é algo que eu apenas sei.

Alguém saberia explicar se há alguma regra para isto, e caso sim, qual é a regra?

Comment: Fabrício, fazes duas perguntas diferentes: a do título pergunta o motivo, a do texto pergunta se há ou não regras. No que estás interessado?

Comment: @Schilive a questão é que eu não quis assumir que houvesse uma regra, pois nunca ouvi falar dela caso exista, então por isso escrevi na última linha perguntando se existe alguma regra para este caso? e caso sim como ela é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De fato, não existe uma regra em específico que determine que um país, estado ou cidade seja ou não acompanhado por artigo. Vários nomes, porém, tem a ausência de artigo justificada, mas cada caso é um caso. Entender quais nomes acompanham artigo é um processo de tentativa e erro. Conforme o vocabulário do ouvinte se expande, analogias podem ser feitas para nomes de países nunca antes lidos... Ainda assim, não existe uma regra formal, apesar de podermos perceber alguns padrões:

Por exemplo, São Tomé e Príncipe não vem acompanhado de artigo, pois, se eu dissesse "O São Tomé e Príncipe", eu daria a entender que estou me referindo ao próprio São Tomé, e não ao país em si.

Outros países, como Moçambique e Madagascar, não possuem gênero evidente em sua pronúncia, devido à pronúncia estrangeira, e portanto não seguem acompanhados de artigo.

Outros países possuem uma pronúncia variada. Angola, por exemplo, geralmente não vêm acompanhada de artigo, mas é tratado como feminino. É comum ouvir que algo é "da Angola" ao invés de ser "de Angola", o que não ocorre com outros nomes, como Portugal, que nunca vem acompanhado de artigo.

Países que possuem nomes compostos, ou que já possuem artigo em sua pronúncia mais popular (por exemplo, que são acompanhados do "the" em sua pronúncia em inglês), também são acompanhados de artigos, como acontece, por exemplo, com As Filipinas, Os Estados Unidos, A Costa do Marfim, O Reino Unido, Os Países Baixos,  etc. Vale à pena notar que, nestes casos, a presença do artigo permite que o ouvinte diferencie **o** país de **um** objeto. Por exemplo, se eu disser apenas "países baixos", pode ser entendido que eu me refiro à qualquer país abaixo do nível do mar, porém quando eu digo "Os Países Baixos", fica claro que eu me refiro especificamente à Holanda.

Países com nomes terminados em "tão" são todos masculinos, como o Afeganistão, o Cazaquistão, o Turcomenistão, o Paquistão, etc.